# Query related to mathematical reasoning

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was studying mathematical reasoning and I guess my book did not explain the rules properly .

There is this statement-:

All natural numbers are even or odd.

This statement seems kind of correct because a natural number is even or odd. But if you try to break it in two component statements then

Statement-1 is "All natural numbers are even " which is false .

Statement-2 is "All natural numbers are odd" which again is false .

So in "and" conjunction if both component statements are false then the statement must be false .

So where did I go wrong? and if this statement is actually false in mathematical language then how should we say "all natural are even or odd"? I mean I want to say like there are only 2 cases for a natural it is even or odd.

Comment: $(\forall x)(A(x)\vee B(x))$ does not imply $(\forall x)(A(x))\vee(\forall x)(B(x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the statement "All natural numbers are even AND All natural numbers are odd" is indeed a false statement. This is equivalent to saying "All natural numbers are even AND odd", which is false, because in fact there is no natural number that is both even and odd. The problem is "**All** natural numbers ...." It's the quantifier that needs to be changed, a true statement would be "There exists a natural number that is even" and the analogous statement for odd natural numbers. With this, you have two numbers, $n_1$ and $n_2$ that are even and odd respectively. Then, showing that under modulo $2$ every number in $\mathbb{N}$ is congruent to either $n_1$ (which is even) or $n_2$ (which is odd), you have shown that *every* natural number is even *or* odd.

Comment: sorry i wanted to write "or " conjucture

Comment: Ok, could you clarify where you still have confusion?

Comment: my doubt is exactly that how should i write "every natural number is even or odd" , because if you break this into 2 components statements then one is "every natural number is even" and "every natural number is odd" and by or conjucture this statement is false .

Comment: "Every natural number is even or odd" can be written: "$n \in \mathbb{N} \implies (\exists k \in \mathbb{N} \ni n = 2k) \vee (\exists k \in \mathbb{N} \ni n = 2k+1)$"

Comment: oh okay its like "If n is a natural number then it is odd or even"???

Comment: yes that's what I wrote. In English, we could break it down: "Every number is even or odd" becomes "Some numbers (possibly none) are even, and the remaining numbers are odd". Thus, we obtain two true statements: "Every number that's not odd is even" *and* "Every number that's not even is odd". Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

A natural number is even if it can be written as $2k$, $k = 0, 1, 2, 3,... $ and odd if it can be written $2k+1$, $k=0,1,2,3...$. Notice that the two sets are disjoint, and together produce $0, 1, 2, 3, ... = \mathbb{N}$. That is what it means that "all natural numbers are even or odd": they are disjoint sets whose union is $\mathbb{N}$.

You should be careful, though, that logical or means "case a or case b (or both)".

Comment: yeah I want to know how should write "a natural is either even or odd " in mathematical language